# SQL removing arithmatic from GROUP BY hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I currently have a query that works fine in SQL, but I need it to run in Hibernate. It finds the number of records of 2 fields inside of a time window. However, a quick google search will tell you that you can't have an arithmetic expression in the `GROUP BY` clause in hibernate.

My table/SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE T ( 
    Field_1 CHAR(4),
    Field_2 CHAR(4),
    Time_Stamp Date
);

--Populated

DECLARE @DATE1 DATE, @DATE2 DATE, @INTERVAL INT;
@DATE1 = TO_DATE('2013-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
@DATE2 = TO_DATE('2013-01-02', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
@INTERVAL = 15;

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(Field_1) as field1, 
        COUNT(Field_2) as field2, 
        FLOOR( TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( Time_Stamp, 'hhmi' ) ) / @INTERVAL ) as timeInterval
    FROM T
    WHERE Time_Stamp BETWEEN @DATE1 AND @DATE2
    GROUP BY FLOOR( TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( Time_Stamp, 'hhmi' ) ) / @INTERVAL )
) ORDER BY timeInterval ASC;
```

As you can see I can remove the `ORDER BY` so that there is no arithmetic in it using a subquery. Is it possible to do something similar in this instance with the `GROUP BY` clause or some other work around?

I have the query already written in hibernate, and can translate between the two fine, I only need the structure of the query so the arithmetic is outside of the group by funciton, SQL syntax is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform your calculation in inner query then group by the result of it.

```
SELECT 
        COUNT(Field_1) as field1, 
        COUNT(Field_2) as field2,
        timeInterval
 FROM (
    SELECT 
        Field_1,
        Field_2,
        FLOOR( TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( Time_Stamp, 'hhmi' ) ) / @INTERVAL ) as timeInterval
    FROM T
    WHERE Time_Stamp BETWEEN @DATE1 AND @DATE2
) 
GROUP BY timeInterval
ORDER BY timeInterval ASC;
```